# How to generate oauth 2.0 token using "Create Client Oauth2 Session" keyword in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
Token&{head}=Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Create Client Oauth2 Session    temp    token_url=https://websec-qa.cable.comcast.com/as/token.oauth2    tenant_id=customerequipmentqa    tenant_secret=ac975251ba4349acbb962955876ec404    base_url=https://ce-service-qa.u1.app.cloud.comcast.net/xnet/ced/1.0/messages    headers=&{head}    verify=${True}
```

I am getting below error:

> MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied

Perhaps you meant http://None?

Answer (score 2):

```
Check Webservice
${token_string}=    Set Variable    Bearer    
Create Session    webservice    ${BASE_TOKEN_URL}    verify=${True}
${data}=    Create Dictionary    token_name=customerequipment    grant_type=client_credentials    client_id=customerequipmentqa    client_secret=ac975251ba4349acbb962955876ec404    scope=xnet:customerequipment
${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
${resp}=    Post Request    webservice    /as/token.oauth2    data=${data}    headers=${headers}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
${token}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
${stripped_token}=    Strip String    ${token}
${token_string}=    Catenate    ${token_string}    ${stripped_token}
[Return]    ${token_string}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is best to provide a complete example, that also includes the specific libraries that are loaded. In this case a quick search on the keyword revealed that it's most likely the [Extended Requests Library](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-extendedrequestslibrary/doc/ExtendedRequestsLibrary.html). With a few minor alterations I get a different error message that should be correct.

```
*** Settings ***                
Library ExtendedRequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    #Token
    &{head}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Create Client Oauth2 Session    
    ...    label=temp    
    ...    token_url=https://websec-qa.cable.comcast.com/as/token.oauth2    
    ...    tenant_id=customerequipmentqa    
    ...    tenant_secret=ac975251ba4349acbb962955876ec404    
    ...    base_url=https://ce-service-qa.u1.app.cloud.comcast.net/xnet/ced/1.0/messages    
    ...    headers=${head}    
    ...    verify=${True}
```

Results in

> Starting test: oAuth.Question2.TC 20180618 19:40:27.794 : INFO :
>   &{head} = { Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded } 20180618
>   19:40:48.820 : FAIL : ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
>   error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host')) Ending test: oAuth.Question2.TC

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach:-

```
Create Session   baseUri   https://xxxxxx.xx.xxx/xxx/xx      verify=True
&{params}=  Create Dictionary   client_id=${client_id}   client_secret=${client_secret}   grant_type=${grant_type}
&{headers}=  Create Dictionary   Content-Type=application/json
${resp}=  Post Request  baseUri  /oauth/token    none    none    ${params}  ${headers}
Log to Console  ${resp.json()['access_token']}
Status Should Be 200            ${resp}
```

Answer (score -1):

So below is my code, however, I am getting 400!= 200

```
*** Keywords ***
Generate Token
    ${token_string}=    Set Variable    Bearer
    create session   my_session     https://qa3-apiv2.xxx.com/oauth2    verify=${True}
    ${data1}=    create dictionary  grant_type=password    client_id=9cde7c7dcf4d47772a068bf24ca0f518657a5f84    client_secret=cf102c871fe20a85c3dfb9d4d114eebccace168b   username=qa3test_admin   password=Password123#
    ${resp}=     Post Request     my_session      /token.php    data=${data1}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
    ${token}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
    Log    ${resp.content}
```

Comment: You need to include header to make it work. For eg- "${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"