# Post Requests Failed to capture the access token in Robot Framework

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, robotframework, access-token

```
** Settings ***
Library     RequestsLibrary
Library     Collections

*** Variables ***
${SERVICE_ROOT}    https://xxx.yyy.org/m1/oauth
${SERVICE_NAME}    accesstoken
${client_key}      11111111111111111111111111111111111
${client_secret}   2222222222222222222222222222222222222222


*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    Create access token

*** Keywords ***
Create access token
    Create Session  accessurl   ${SERVICE_ROOT}     verify=True
    &{data_1}       Create Dictionary  grant_type=client_credentials  key=${client_key}  secret=${client_secret}

    ${header}       Create Dictionary     Content-Type=application/json

    ${resp}         Post Request    accessurl  /token   params=${data_1}     headers=${header}  

    Should be Equal    ${resp.status_code}    200
```

In simple words, I am trying to replicate the POST METHOD from Postman to Robot Framework (Type oauth 2 )
Mandatory parameters are *grant type*, *client id and secret*.
**Expected Authorization**: Bearer with access token

Upon executing, I am getting **401** and ***params* returns Empty** I had tried all possible ways to generate the token by making changes in the code but all proved to be unsuccessful. Kindly help me to fix this and let me know what error I have made,
I am very new to automation scripting.

Comment: are you certain that the key and secret are accurate? Did you accidentally include quotes around the secret or key? Are there special characters in the secret or key (eg: backslashes)?

Comment: @BryanOakley,  key and secret are accurate : Tested in postman and its working. No quotes and special characters included in the key/secret.

Comment: Is the grant type supposed to be `client_credential` or `client_credentials`? In a comment to my answer you said that `client_crediential` (singlular) worked, but in your question you're using `client_credentials` (plural)

Comment: @BryanOakley, that was typo error from my end in the comment section. It is client_credentials and same was used in post request.

Comment: @BryanOakley, finally was able to find the solution to this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: You should either close this question, or post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Solution: Referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910964/how-to-generate-oauth-2-0-token-using-create-client-oauth2-session-keyword-in/50914903#50914903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Referred [How to generate oauth 2.0 token using "Create Client Oauth2 Session" keyword in robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910964/how-to-generate-oauth-2-0-token-using-create-client-oauth2-session-keyword-in/50914903#50914903)

The above worked.